# trigger a macro by clicking on merged range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, named-ranges

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(abc)) Is Nothing Then
        Call MyMacro
    End If

End If
End Sub
```

this code works fine when I put for example range("A1") so that clicking on A1 triggers the macro, now I have a merged range W20:Z20, I referenced the range as ABC, now when I go back to my sheet to try to click on the cell it gives me the error"compile error, variable not defined"

Comment: Use `Range("abc")`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to superuser.

As Máté Juhász said, if you put the "abc" within `If Not Intersect(Target, Range(abc)) Is Nothing Then` in quotes, your code should work.

That line of your code would look like this:

`If Not Intersect(Target, Range("abc")) Is Nothing Then`